# Why doesn't the sum of daily percentage changes of a stock index over a given time period, equals the period percentage change?

Tags: calculus, finance

The following is the simplified version of an actual model. It is only meant to exemplify the issue I am having.

I have a large MS-Excel sheet of 29953 rows containing the daily closing values of the Dow Jones (DJIA) since 1900/01/03. Row 1 contains the Column headers. Column A contains the Date, column B the DJIA, Column C the daily change percentages.
The entire C column contains the daily closing percentage gain/loss using the following formula starting at C3 and copied all the way down: =(B3-B2)/B2.

**Calculation_A.**
If I wish, for example, to compute the percentage gain between 1900/01/03 and now (2016-11-29), I use the following formula: =(B29953-B2)/B2 which using the actual values translates to (19121.6 - 66.6) / 66.6 = 286.068. This is, I think, the correct result.

**Calculation_B.**
Calculation_B is the sum of the daily percentage changes (calculated in column C) corresponding, in Excel, to the formula =SUM(C2:C29953) resulting to 767.812.

Intuitively, I would have assumed that Calculation_A = Calculation_B.

My question are as follows, why (mathematically) are Calculation_A and Calculation_B yielding different results? Is there a way to make calculation_B consistent with Calculation_A?

I don't consider myself particularly optuse, but I am having a hard time solving this seemingly trivial problem. Are integrals the answer? Thanks in advance!

---

**Update#1.**
Following the very good comments and answers from Brian and DougM, thank you, I was able to reconcile the two calculations on my initial PL1DAY column.

I now have another issue along the same line: 
I have a Excel column named PL20DAYS which calculates, for each trading day, the percentage gain/loss 20 days forward: i.e. (DAYn+20 - DAYn)/DAYn.
Why would the compounding of the PL20DAYS column not equate the compounding of the PL1DAY?

Comment: Compounding... the long run return is $(1+r_1)(1+r_2)\cdots(1+r_n)-1$ where $r_n$ are the short run returns.  In the extreme case, if you are up 100% on Monday, and down 100% on Tuesday, you are broke.  If you are up 100% on Monday and down 50% on Tuesday you have broken even.  In Excel try "=product(A1:A1000 + 1)-1"

Comment: Consider the simple case of $2$ days, with a gain of $50\%$ on the first, and a loss of $50\%$ next. The sum of daily percentage changes is $0$, but the $2$-day change is obviously negative.

Comment: Think of it this way: on your column C you have fractions with different denominators. Would you add them?

Comment: @DougM. Thanks DougM, I get the idea. Implemented it using 2 intermediary columns. Got 301.7 which is not the expected 286 value. I don't think it comes from rounding errors. Would you have an excel specific formula or approach?

Comment: @DougM -- You answered while I was typing my first comment. I'll catchup with everyone comments & answers and get back to the post later.

Comment: Yah, I put it in my previous post.  "=PRODUCT(A1:A1000 +1)-1"  I have decided that your data lives in column A, and you have 1000 rows, but I am sure you figured that part out.  Other than that.  The data must be in % format, and you will need to hit "shift+enter" because that formula is technically an array.

Comment: @DougM Thanks Doug for your math answer augmented with the correct Excel formula. As a side comment for future readers, the actual keystrokes for entering arrays are Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a very simple example: suppose that some quantity increases by $100\%$ and then again by $100\%$
. A $100\%$ increase means that the quantity doubles. Here it doubles and then doubles again. Thus, if its initial value is $x$, it first doubles to $2x$ and then doubles again to $2\cdot 2x=4x$. It is now $400\%$ of its original value, not $100\%+100\%=200\%$.

Successive percentage increases are multiplicative, not additive. When something increases by $p$ percent, it is multiplied by $1+\frac{p}{100}$. If you now increase it by $q$ percent, you're multiplying the increased amount by $1+\frac{q}{100}$. The combined effect is to multiply the original quantity by

$$\left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)\left(1+\frac{q}{100}\right)=1+\frac{p+q}{100}+\frac{pq}{10000}\;;$$

assuming that $p\ne 0\ne q$, this is clearly not the same as multiplying by $1+\frac{p+q}{100}$ to get an increase of $p+q\%$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. With hindsight it makes total sense.

Comment: I implemented Doug M correct solution he posted as a comment. I understand now the multiplicative (compounding) logic. Having said that, I have another issue along the same line: If I have a column that contains the forward 20day gain/loss percentage, shouldn't its compounding be based on your same formula?

Comment: @Kanarinox: You're welcome. If that percentage is the percentage change in a $20$ day period, then it's a one-time calculation based on the value at the beginning of the $20$ day period and the value at the end of the period. That should agree with the compounded value of the $20$ individual daily changes.

Comment: I am new to this great site and so missed your reply until now. Let me step back: i have a column (PL20Days), for each of my 29953 trading days, with the pct value of the market return 20 days forward. (DAYn+20 - DAYn)/DAYn. For some reason the compounding formula of the PL20DAYS column returns an aberration compared to  (DAY29953 - DAY1)/DAY1. What am i missing?